# Pandas - Outer Join on Column with Repeating Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, outer-join

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, please let me know how I can help you help me if my question is unclear.

Goal: Use Python and Pandas to Outer join (or merge) Data Sets containing different experimental trials where the "x" axis of each trial is extremely similar but has some deviations. Most importantly, the "x" axis increases, hits a maximum and then decreases, often overlapping with previously existing "x" points.

Problem: When I go to join/merge the datasets on "x", the "x" column is sorted, messing up the order of the collected data and making it impossible to plot it correctly.

Here is a small example of what I am trying to do:

Wouldn't let me add pictures because I am new. Here is the code to generate these example data sets.

Data Sets :

[image: Example - Trial 1 Data]

[image: Example - Trial 2 Data]

Import:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rand
```

Code :

```
T1 = {'x':np.array([1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,5,2,1]),'y':np.array([10000,8500,7400,6450,5670,5100,4600,4500,8400,9000]),'z':np.array(rand.sample(range(0,10000),10))}'

T2 = {'x':np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,2,1.5,1]),'y':np.array([10500,7700,5500,4560,4300,3900,3800,5400,8400,8800]),'z':np.array(rand.sample(range(0,10000),10))}
Trial1 = pd.DataFrame(T1)
Trial2 = pd.DataFrame(T2)
```

Attempt to Merge/Join:

```
WomboCombo  = Trial1.join(Trial2,how='outer',lsuffix=1,rsuffix=2, on='x')
WomboCombo2 = pd.merge(left=Trial1, right= Trial2, how = 'outer', left
```

Attempt to split into two parts, increasing and decreasing part (manually found row number where data "x" starts decreasing):

```
Trial1Inc = Trial1[0:8]
Trial2Inc = Trial2[0:7]
```

Result - Merge works well, join messes with the "x" column, not sure why:

```
Trial1Inc.merge(Trial2Inc,on='x',how='outer', suffixes=[1,2])
```

[Incrementing section Merge Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgH1T.png)

```
Trial1Inc.join(Trial2Inc,on='x',how='outer', lsuffix=1,rsuffix=2)
```

[Incrementing section Join Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhg5m.png)
Hopefully my example is clear, the "x" column in Trial 1 increases until 5, then decreases back towards 0. In Trial 2, I altered the test a bit because I noticed that I needed data at a slightly higher "x" value. Trial 2 Increases until 7 and then quickly decreases back towards 0.

My end goal is to plot the average of all y values (where there is overlap between the trials) against the corresponding x values.

If there is overlap I can add error bars. Pandas is almost perfect for what I am trying to do because an Outer join adds null values where there is no overlap and is capable of horizontally concatenating the two trials when there is overlap.

All thats left now is to figure out how to join on the "x" column but maintain its order of increasing values and then decreasing values. The reason it is important for me to first increase "x" and then decrease it is because when looking at the "y" values, it seems as though the initial "y" value at a given "x" is greater than the "y" value when "x" is decreasing (E.G. in trial 1 when x=1, y=10000, however, later in the trial when we come back to x=1, y=9000, this trend is important. When Pandas sorts the column before merging, instead of there being a clean curve showing a decrease in "y" as "x" increases and then the reverse, there are vertical downward jumps at any point where the data was joined.

I would really appreciate any help with either:

A) a perfect solution that lets me join on "x" when "x" contains duplicates

B) an efficient way to split the data sets into increasing "x" and decreasing "x" so that I can merge the increasing and decreasing sections of each trial separately and then vertically concat them.

Hopefully I did an okay job explaining the problem I would like to solve. Please let me know if I can clarify anything,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you add self-contained code including the pd.merge and the import of numpy and rand? The idea I have is to consider merging using the index instead of x. I think that would prevent sorting on x, but I want to try it out in code before answering.

Comment: You can split up each dataframe into two parts based on "x" values (the first half monotonically increasing and the second half monotonically decreasing) and do the joins separately.

Comment: @DavidGaertner Thanks for the response. I updated my post, please note that the trials don't necessarily have the same number of data points, some have 30 while others have 1000. Looking forward to seeing how we can merge on the index but still make sure to line up all of the "x" values together.

Comment: @xyzjayne I agree with your idea for a work around solution, is there an efficient way to split the data set into two? One half increasing and the other decreasing?

Answer (score 0):

I think @xyzjayne idea of splitting the dataframe is a great idea.

Splitting Trial1 and Trial2:

```
# index of max x value in Trial2
t2_max_index = Trial2.index[Trial2['x'] == Trial2['x'].max()].tolist()
# split Trial2 by max value
trial2_high = Trial2.loc[:t2_max_index[0]].set_index('x')
trial2_low = Trial2.loc[t2_max_index[0]+1:].set_index('x')

# index of max x value in Trial1
t1_max_index = Trial1.index[Trial1['x'] == Trial1['x'].max()].tolist()
# split Trial1 by max vlaue
trial1_high = Trial1.loc[:t1_max_index[0]].set_index('x')
trial1_low = Trial1.loc[t1_max_index[0]+1:].set_index('x')
```

Once we split the dataframes we join the `higher`s together and the `lowers` together:

```
WomboCombo_high = trial1_high.join(trial2_high, how='outer', lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2', on='x').reset_index()
WomboCombo_low = trial1_low.join(trial2_low, how='outer', lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2', on='x').reset_index()
```

We now combine them toegther to have one dataframe `WomboCombo`

```
WomboCombo = WomboCombo_high.append(WomboCombo_low)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    x   y1      z1      y2       z2
0   1.0 10000.0 3425.0  10500.0 3061.0
1   1.5 8500.0  5059.0  NaN     NaN
2   2.0 7400.0  2739.0  7700.0  7090.0
3   2.5 6450.0  9912.0  NaN     NaN
4   3.0 5670.0  2099.0  5500.0  1140.0
5   3.5 5100.0  9637.0  NaN     NaN
6   4.0 4600.0  7581.0  4560.0  9584.0
7   5.0 4500.0  8616.0  4300.0  3940.0
8   6.0 NaN     NaN     3900.0  5896.0
9   7.0 NaN     NaN     3800.0  6211.0
0   2.0 8400.0  3181.0  5400.0  9529.0
2   1.5 NaN     NaN     8400.0  3260.0
1   1.0 9000.0  4280.0  8800.0  8303.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to give you trial rows specific IDs an then merge on the IDs. Should keep the x values from being sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was trying out, but it doesn't address varying numbers of data points. I like gym-hh's answer, though it's not clear to me that you wanted two columns of y,z pairs. So you could combine his ideas and this code to get what you need.

```
Trial1['index1'] = Trial1.index
Trial2['index1'] = Trial2.index
WomboCombo = Trial1.append(Trial2)
WomboCombo.sort_values(by=['index1'],inplace=True) 
WomboCombo
```

Output:

```
    x   y   z   index1
0   1.0 10000   7148    0
0   1.0 10500   2745    0
1   1.5 8500    248 1
1   2.0 7700    9505    1
2   2.0 7400    6380    2
2   3.0 5500    3401    2
3   2.5 6450    6183    3
3   4.0 4560    5281    3
4   3.0 5670    99  4
4   5.0 4300    8864    4
5   3.5 5100    5132    5
5   6.0 3900    7570    5
6   4.0 4600    9951    6
6   7.0 3800    7447    6
7   2.0 5400    3713    7
7   5.0 4500    3863    7
8   1.5 8400    8776    8
8   2.0 8400    1592    8
9   1.0 9000    2167    9
9   1.0 8800    782 9
```